# C#, WPF, bind List<string> to DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

I have trouble to bind a List to a DataGrid. It should be as simple as possible. I'm new to WPF and this is for my personal education.

I have a View(Editor),ViewModel(VMText) and a Data(JustText) class.

My source so far:

**JustText.cs**

```
namespace Model
{
    public class Text
    {
        private string _code;
        public string Code
        {
            get { return _code;  }
            set { _code = value; }
        }

        public Text()
        {
            _code = "Hello World!\nHow you doin'?";
        }
    } 
}
```

**VMText.cs**

```
namespace ViewModel
{
    public class VMText
    {    
        private Model.Text _code;

        public List<string> Code
        {            
            get { return new List<string>(_code.Code.Split('\n'));        }
            set { _code.Code = System.String.Join("\n", value.ToArray()); }
        }

        private View.Editor editor;

        public VMText(View.Editor editor)
        {
            _code = new Model.Text();
            this.editor = editor; 
        }
    }
}
```

**Editor.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="View.Editor"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:View"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Editor" Height="240.024" Width="269.895">
    <Grid Background="#FF292929" Margin="0,0,-6.8,0.4">
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                  Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Width="200pt"
                  Height="100pt"
                  DataContext="{Binding vmText}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Code, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Foreground="Black" Width="60" Header="Test" IsReadOnly="false" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Editor.xaml.cs**

```
namespace View
{
    public partial class Editor : Window
    {
        private ViewModel.VMText vmText;

        #region Constructor

        public Editor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            vmText = new ViewModel.VMText(this);
            DataContext = vmText;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

I just want to show List which is created in VMText in one column in the DataGrid

Comment: Looks like you need to set the ItemsSource property on the DataGrid.

Comment: `public List<string> Code {...}` is you collection of data for DataGrid, so Bind it in `<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ... ItemsSource="{Binding Code}">`

Comment: 1) `ItemsSource="{Binding Code}"`. Don't set `DataContext` on the grid at all; it inherits that from the view. 2) That `ItemsSource` binding won't *replace* `Code`; it'll edit the items *in* `Code`, which happens to be impossible the way you've written it. With the viewmodel that you have, all you can do is display the items in `Code`. So `Code` needs to change: It has to be an `ObservableCollection` of a class that has a property the grid can edit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I guess you simply want to display the strings in the Code source collection property of the view model in the DataGrid. You should

- then bind the `ItemsSource` property of the DataGrid to the Code source property of the view model
- and then bind the DataGridTextColumn to the strings in the Code list itself.

You just have to modify the XAML markup of your view a bit to be able to see the strings. Try this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="0,0,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="200pt"
        Height="100pt"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Code}"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
   <DataGridTextColumn 
        Header="Test" IsReadOnly="false" 
        Binding="{Binding}" 
        Foreground="Black" 
        Width="60" />
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is working. I tried it with Binding="{Binding Path =.}, too and it is working too. But it is still 'try and error'. I have to figure out the concept of binding.

Comment: {Binding} is short for {Binding Path =.}: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750413(v=vs.110).aspx. Please remember to accept an answer and vote helpful ones up.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't understand why I got an additional column called `Length`... this was caused by the missing `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` property on the DataGrid.

Answer (score 3):

You should implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) to notify binding that property changed. Also for the collections look at `ObservableCollection` instead of `List`.

Answer (score 1):

Bind VMText.Code to DataGrid ItemSource. You don't need to Inicialize DataGrid DataContract in View when you do it in code behind.

**ViewModel**

```
namespace ViewModel
{
    public class VMText : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public VMText(View.Editor editor)
        {
            _code = new Model.Text();
            this.editor = editor; 
        }

        public List<string> Code
        {            
            get
            {
                return new List<string>(_code.Code.Split('\n'));
            }
            set
            {
                _code.Code = System.String.Join("\n", value.ToArray());
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Code");
            }
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private Model.Text _code;

        private View.Editor editor;
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<Window x:Class="View.Editor"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:View"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Editor" Height="240.024" Width="269.895">
<Grid Background="#FF292929" Margin="0,0,-6.8,0.4">
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              Margin="0,0,0,0" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Width="200pt"
              Height="100pt"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Code}>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Code"
                                Foreground="Black" Width="60"
                                Header="Test"
                                IsReadOnly="false" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```